# drupal,cck---Remove "N/A" from list of radio button choices

Tags: drupal, module, cck

the follow code is from it's documentation,it's too abstract. expect someone can help me how to do it.

Removing CCK N/A field using a preprocess function...

Before you assign your radios to a variable use the following code:

```
 <?php
unset($vars['form']['group_if_in_fieldset']['field_the_radios']['value']['']); //remove  the pesky CCK N/A radio
?>
```

i have put the code into the mytheme_preprocess_node(){} but it can't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to remove N/A then make the field required, it should go away.

Comment: Yes, this will do it. Easy, and no messing around with pre-process functions!

Comment: yeah,you're right. could you tell me how to write the key of the array $vars? what these ['form']['group_if_in_fieldset']['field_the_radios']['value']['']);  stand? if i want to write it for my form, how should i write? thank you

Comment: Well, examine $vars itself. if you have the devel module you can do dpm($vars); and you can easily find what you're looking for. otherwise you can do print_r($vars); (wrap it in <pre>'s for readability).

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the strings used as indices are only placeholders. If you have created a CCK field called "item_status", your field will likely be called "field_item_status", not "field_the_radios". Same goes to the fieldset group name (if you happen to have your radios in a group).